# What kind of error will result from attempting to access a derived class member function through a base class pointer?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, derived-class

Say we have a pointer `bp` to a base class object, and a pointer `dp` to a derived class, and set `bp = dp`. Will attempting to access a derived class member function through the base pointer result in a compile-time error or a run-time error?

Comment: Try it and you'll see.

Comment: compile time if function in dp is not an override of bp function

Comment: Look up polymorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the method is in the Base class then it will run. If it is not in the Base class then it will cause a compile time error that it cannot access that method. This is an integral part of polymorphism and dynamic binding.